# How much unhappiness is generated from cities and citizens?

Tags: civilization-5

At first glance, I really like India's bonus:

> Double the Unhappiness from the number of Cities, but Halve the Unhappiness from Population size.

For me to really judge it though, and build strategies around it, I need to know how  much unhappiness is normally generated from cities and citizens. Unfortunately, I don't know this, and my google-fu is failing me today.

How much unhappiness is generated from cities and citizens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to check out the resources and happiness tab on the Economic Overview, since the exact formula varies depending on map size and culture bonuses.  It also changes sometimes in patches.

[image]

The base formula as of this time is 3 per city, and one per population (Or 1.34 for occupied cities).  You can also find/change these values in the GlobalDefines.XML file.

> UNHAPPINESS_PER_POPULATION 1
>
> UNHAPPINESS_PER_OCCUPIED_POPULATION 1.34
>
> UNHAPPINESS_PER_CITY 3

The modifiers for map size are found in CIV5Worlds.XML.  As of this time, all levels use the values above except for Large (80% of the above values) and Huge (60% of the above values).  This affects both population and city unhappiness equally.

In terms of evaluating Gandhi's ability, keep in mind that the maximum happiness you can gain from a city is equal to its population.  So for anyone else, you can never do better than -3 happiness per city (without culture bonuses).  For Gandhi, you start at -6, but at 12 population you could theoretically have a net 0 happiness from the city. So Gandhi can theoretically have MORE cities than others, even though the intent is to encourage you to have fewer.

Comment: +1, your formula matches what I'm seeing in-game to a greater extent.

Comment: Are you able to provide any more information on how map size affects the unhappiness gained per city/citizen?

Comment: @Wipq Yah, I can take some more time tonight to dig through the XML files and add the details on the map size modifiers.

Comment: It's not as if Civ's depiction of Ghandi has ever been accurate anyway..."Our words are backed with NUCLEAR ARMS!"

Answer (score 0):

what bwarner says + Map size modifies per city penalty. On largest map its reduced to something around 70-80% (I don't have game at hand, someone please fill correct value).
So if you like and your computer can handle largest map, ghandi is crushingly best there