# How much unhappiness do puppet cities generate?

Tags: civilization-5

How much unhappiness do puppet cities generate, and how does that interact with India's bunus:

> Double the Unhappiness from the number of Cities, but Halve the
>   Unhappiness from Population size.

Related to [How much unhappiness is generated from cities and citizens?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51771/how-much-unhappiness-is-generated-from-cities-and-citizens)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puppet cities cause the same amount of unhappiness as a city you build yourself. Only annexed cities (or cities in the process of being razed) have a different formula for unhappiness.

Sources: http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Happiness_%28Civ5%29#Unhappiness_Causes, http://www.carlsguides.com/strategy/civilization5/happiness.php, personal observations